# Sending a value in header in MVC Action request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC C# Project and I have to send some certain value that comes from a drop-down list in the GUI with the header of every request.

I have both normal MVC requests.(@Html.Action....)
and ajax requests.

I wrote this code for all ajax requests in the _Layout:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("currentMandantId", getCurrentMandant());
      }
 });
```

how to do the same thing for all other types of requests (not just Ajax)?

thank you.

Comment: try using module, see example here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34953360/5519026)

Comment: this won't work with me, because the value that I want to send it using the header is dynamic comes from GUI dropdown list.

Comment: Maybe just convert Html.Action into javascript and use jQuery.ajax. That may be the simplest solution.

Comment: himm, thanks. I am thinking of override the click of all anchor and use XMLHttpRequest to send the request. do you think it could work?

Comment: If your links do actual navigation, then you will most likely send back a full view, which jquery won't like much.  Does it have to be header that you have set? seems like a bad choice as you have to step smartly to implement it.  I'd favour a parameter in the url in most situations, much less work than developing an SPA to handle all content as partials

Comment: unfortunately, my project Manager wants it in the header to make the request cleaner.
Besides how to call a page in ajax request? I mean if I have an [a] and I need to convert it into Ajax. how can I do it. it will give a result but not a redirect.